# SQL query with multiple values iteration like for each

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join

Table: detail1

```
LN_ID       LN_DATE   LN_CATG
----------  --------  -------
1693834961  8/1/2013        16
1693834961  7/1/2013        16
1693834961  6/1/2013         4
1693834961  5/1/2013        16
1693834962  8/1/2013        16
1693834962  7/1/2013        16
1693834962  6/1/2013        16
1693834962  5/1/2013         5
```

Table: detail2

```
LN_ID       LN_MOD_DATE  LN_PYMT_DATE
----------  -----------  ------------
1693834961  8/1/2012     1/1/2011
1693834961  9/1/2011     2/1/2011
1693834962  10/1/2012    3/1/2012
```

Result:

```
LN_ID      FIRST_DT  LAST_DT   LN_MOD_DT  LN_PYMT_DT
---------- --------  --------  ---------  ----------
1693834961 8/1/2013  6/1/2013  8/1/2012    1/1/2011
```

Query:

```
SELECT ln_id, first_dt, last_dt, ln_mod_dt, ln_pymt_dt  FROM 
(SELECT   a.ln_id ln_id, a.ln_date first_dt, 
                 b.ln_date last_dt, c.ln_mod_date ln_mod_dt,
                 c.ln_pymt_date ln_pymt_dt
            FROM detail1 a,
                 (SELECT *
                    FROM (SELECT   *
                              FROM detail1
                             WHERE ln_id = '1693834961'
                               AND ln_catg <> 16
                          ORDER BY ln_date DESC)
                   WHERE ROWNUM < 2) b,
                 (SELECT *
                    FROM (SELECT   *
                              FROM detail2
                             WHERE ln_id  = '1693834961'
                          ORDER BY ln_mod_date DESC)
                   WHERE ROWNUM < 2) c
           WHERE a.ln_id = b.ln_id
             AND a.ln_id = c.ln_id
             AND a.ln_catg = 16
        ORDER BY a.ln_date DESC)
 WHERE ROWNUM < 2
```

I need to find the first(latest) and last date where the ln_catg = 16 consecutively from the detail1 table for each LN_ID.

For example the Expected ouput as ,

```
   LN_ID      FIRST_DT  LAST_DT   LN_MOD_DT  LN_PYMT_DT
    ---------- --------  --------  ---------  ----------
    1693834961 8/1/2013  7/1/2013  8/1/2012    1/1/2011
    1693834962 8/1/2013  6/1/2013  8/1/2012    1/1/2012
    --------
```

this works seems good when the query execute against one ln_id at at time but our expectation would be this same kind of query should execute against more than one ids at a time.

is that possible add kind of for-each or adding any other  where Or IN Condtion to pass the different iD's? since the ln_id hard code in the sub queries not sure how do i use one and another and execute..

any help would be apperciated.

Comment: how is this table 2 mod_date is been fetched .I mean which row to pic,is based on what condition.And in case there is only one record in table 1 ,then what will be the first and the last date

Comment: both table combined with ln_id . if there are more than one record in the detail2 table i should pick the latest record from that.if there is only 1 record in the first table it will return null or the same record ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do it?

```
SELECT 
    D1.LN_ID, 
    MAX(D1.LN_DATE) AS FIRST_DT, 
    MAX(D1_A.LN_DATE) AS LAST_DT, 
    MAX(D2.LN_MOD_DATE) AS LN_MOD_DT, 
    MAX(D2.LN_PYMT_DATE) AS LN_PYMT_DT  
FROM 
    DETAIL1 D1
    INNER JOIN DETAIL2 D2 ON D1.LN_ID=D2.LN_ID
    INNER JOIN DETAIL1 D1_A ON D1_A.LN_ID=D1.LN_ID
WHERE 
    D1.LN_CATG = 16 
    AND D1_A.LN_CATG = 16 
    AND D1_A.LN_DATE < D1.LN_DATE
GROUP BY 
    D1.LN_ID
```

Comment: thanks Jymbo. only one correction needed as when the detail2 table has more than one record for the ln_id then i should only pick the latest (max(ln_mod_date)) record.but now its returning the both records.I did tried but seems it does always returns both..

Comment: Can you give me an example data set from your data that is returning both? I used the data set you posted in the question and am only getting 1 record each for 1693834961 and 1693834962

Comment: I did updated the Table: detail2 data set, if the dates are different it pulls the both record for the ln_Id .instead it should take the record which has the greatest D2.LN_MOD_DATE record between any number of records in the the detail2 table for that particular loan Id..  Thanks for your great help.

Comment: @user2309604, I changed the query based on your new data. I believe this should get you what you wanted.

Comment: @user2309604, np man. Just keep in mind this query has all inner joins. If there is only one record in detail1 for a particular LN_ID or there is no associated record in detail2, this query will not return a record. So you may consider changing them to left joins if this is ever the case.